# Node.js can't reacive data from telegram bot websocket

Tags: node.js, ssl, webhooks, telegram-bot

I am trying to set up a telegram bot with nodejs https server with self singed certificate.

ssl certificate:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out crt.pem -subj "/C=IR/ST=A.Sh/L=Tabriz/O=DominoSystem/CN=5.235.36.42"
```

The very simple server:

```
var options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/crt.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    console.log('https server');
    console.log(req.url);
    res.end('yoo hooo');
}).listen(8443,'0.0.0.0');
```

The server is accessible from internet : `https://5.235.36.42:8443/`

Telegram bot setWebhook returns ok `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}`

I can see in my filewall logs and DU Meters "**Open TCP Connections**" that nodejs.exe is receiving a connection from one of telegram's data centers and it always have the status `ESTABLISHED` and sometimes `SYN_RCVD` and then closes with send&receive=0KB but my nodejs server is not receiving any requests.

I have allowed my firewall(Comodo) to ACCEPT all incoming connections on port `8443`.

I have been bashing my head around for 2 days now :( can someone help me pliz...

Windows 8.1 x64, Nodejs 5.9.1

Comment: now, I can't access https://5.235.36.42:8443/ from my site ?

Comment: @this is my personal ip(local dev system) and the node server is not running at the moment

Comment: follow this  : https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/examples/httpsWebHook.js try to add: var bot = new TelegramBot('BOT_TOKEN', options);
bot.setWebHook('IP:PORT/botBOT_TOKEN', __dirname+'/crt.pem');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, fixed it myself, it seems that `Telegram` didn't like the certificate generated by `openssl` on windows (8.1).

I generated the certificate on my linux (CentOS6) server and now it works :D, both in the server and in the local dev machine.